# Error while Installing the items in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7

Am getting the below error while installing items in Sitecore package. It comes for all the packages.

> The insert failed. It conflicted with an identity range check
>   constraint in database 'Sitecore.core', replicated table
>   'dbo.PublishQueue', column 'Index'. If the identity column is
>   automatically managed by replication, update the range as follows: for
>   the Publisher, execute sp_adjustpublisheridentityrange; for the
>   Subscriber, run the Distribution Agent or the Merge Agent. The
>   statement has been terminated.

Comment: So did you try the solutions provided in the error message ?

Comment: We do no have access to production databases.